# If is needed only sometimes, should I always return something?

Tags: php, oop, memory, memory-leaks

I have the following scenario: a class with a method that stores a key-value in array and returns void.
This is the method:

```
<?php
abstract class MyClass
{
    // ...

    protected function setAttribute($name, $value, $skipCasting = null)
    {
        // ...

        $this->attributes[$name] =& $value;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Now, I'm using this method several times in my application and for 50% of times I just set the attribute, for the other 50% of times I also need return the value I'm setting.

I was wondering, in terms of performance, if I'd always return *something* there would be a (significant) **memory loss**?

Comment: The usual practice in OOP is to return $this, that way you can chain setters/other functions

Comment: @Jessica http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now, I'm using this method several times in my application and for 50% of times I just set the attribute, for the other 50% of times I also need return the value I'm setting.

In that case you probably need two different methods a setter and a getter, like this for example:-

```
abstract class MyClass
{
    // ...

    protected function setAttribute($name, $value, $skipCasting = null)
    {
        // ...

        $this->attributes[$name] =& $value;
    }

    public function getAttribute($name)
    {
         return $this->attributes[$name];
    }
}
```

That way you call the applicable function depending on your need.

> I was wondering, in terms of performance, if I'd always return something there would be a (significant) memory loss?

No, nothing to worry about, you can quite safely ignore the returned values of any method or function if you don't need to use them.

Comment: Thanks @vascowhite, actually I already have a getter. The point was avoid to call another method. This could be done if `setAttribute()` already returns a value!

Comment: In that case ignore the first half of my answer :)

Comment: @Jessica There are a few smells around the OP's code, but I didn't want to obfuscate the answer by going into them. That is one of them.

Comment: @Jessica This method is also used to store values via the __get() magic method, in order retrieve them more faster other times in the app. However the point is not about why I have to do something... but if doing it would produce a memory loss or not!!

Comment: It sounds like you're focusing on the wrong things, honestly.

Answer (score 1):

If greatly depends on the interpreter, but in most languages, a return value of a function is simply a value pushed to the stack, then popped by the caller.

In a high-level language such as PHP, that has its own memory manager and garbage collector, worrying about these things is **a bit too much**, but if you are actually worried about it, then it's probably safer just to store the value in a variable, call the function and use it afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Is your primary concern memory allocation/performance?  PHP does its own garbage collection and is usually executed as a singular linear process and therefore memory allocation etc is not really considered.

Its not the best practice to have no interest in memory allocation but in a single threaded, singular process its less important than say in a multi threaded .net based Service.

EDIT:  If youre quite concerned about memory management and this script executes for a long time, check out

http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.gc.php

It shows how to do some garbage collection in long running scripts.